# Jquery readonly input boxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have two (readonly) input textboxes that contain dynamic values.

```
<input class="sum_a" readonly="readonly"  value="0"> 
<input class="sum_b" readonly="readonly"  value="0">
```

I was wondering what would be the best way to preform an action in Jquery every time the value in one or both of these boxes changes. Something along the lines of `$('select[class=sum_a]').change(function()` , but since the user has no interaction with the boxes that wouldn't work.

I'm thinking just to extract the current value and compare it to a previous value each time.

```
sum_a=  parseInt($("input[class='sum_a']").val());
```

could anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using the attribute equals selector to select by class? that's very inefficient compared to selecting by class.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you change the value, trigger the change event.

```
$(".sum_a").val("2").triggerHandler("change");
```

now your change event for said input will be triggered.

Comment: I don't quite understand can you explain it a bit more.

Comment: Since changing the value of an input programmatically doesn't trigger the change event, you can trigger that change yourself to get the same effect. By using my code, you can bind to the change event the way you suggested in your question. `$(".sum_a").change(function(){...});`

Comment: so where I need to trigger the change I use `$(".sum_a").val("2").triggerHandler("change");` but I still keep the `$('select[class=sum_a]').change(function() { }` part, what is the `.val("2")` part?

Comment: That's an example of you changing the value.